# Why and when should I declare a function as noinline in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++

msvc's [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noinline?view=msvc-170) says:

> `__declspec(noinline)` tells the compiler to never inline a particular
> member function (function in a class).
>
> It may be worthwhile to not inline a function if it is small and not
> critical to the performance of your code. That is, if the function is
> small and not likely to be called often, such as a function that
> handles an error condition.
>
> Keep in mind that if a function is marked noinline, the calling
> function will be smaller and thus, itself a candidate for compiler
> inlining.
>
> ```
> class X {
>    __declspec(noinline) int f() {
>       return 0;
>    }   // will not inline
> };
> ```

However, I still cannot understand:

**What are the *differences*, or *benefits*, between**

```
class X {
   __declspec(noinline) int f() {
      return 0;
   }   // will not inline
};
```

**and**

```
class X {
   int f() {
      return 0;
   }
};
```

**?**

Comment: Imagine you have an error handling function that is very small and will easily be inlined.  Now imagine this error basically never happens so the code is dead 99% of the time.  If you have that error code inlined everywhere then your code is larger for basically no reason and larger code can mean slower performance and overall larger binaries.

Comment: @NathanOliver "inlined everywhere" does not necessary mean that code gets larger. If it is "very small and will easily be inlined" then it makes sense to assume the opposite - program size will likely be reduced by inlinning.

Comment: For your very simple example, it's highly unlikely that there is any benefit of noinline. Calling a function needs similar amount of code than setting a register to zero (for example, on x86, calling a function takes 5 bytes, while setting a register to zero is just 2. So it's better to inline.). Inlining will also open more possibilities for the compiler to eliminate some calculations with zero.

Comment: @user7860670 True, but in the context of "error handler" I think it's safe to assume that the function would contain at least one un-inlineable call. Code for throwing exceptions, I've never seen without multiple sys-calls. Logging some error-condition will also involve going to some file, or console, which cannot be inlined. So inlining such a function is guaranteed to make the code larger - as you are replacing one call, with code containing at least another call, if not more. That's what's being refered to by msvc and Nathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, there is no benefit. The compiler has the option of inlining or not inlining a function on a per-call basis, assuming it knows the definition of the function at the call site (either because the function definition is in the same translation unit, or because you've enabled global link-time optimization).

Benefits come down to one of three things: When you want to optimize your code and you think you know better than the compiler, when you explicitly want to keep the function's code from being put in a particular object file, or when you're trying to debug stuff.

In the first case, it is occasionally useful to prohibit inlining to reduce code size, generally to reduce pressure on the instruction cache. This is rarely the case, and should never be done except based on the evidence from a profiler. If you don't know about icache misses then this is not relevant to you, and enabling global link-time optimization and profile-guided optimization are far easier and more effective approaches to getting inlining "right".

In the second case, you may occasionally want to make one object file the sole object file that needs to be recompiled when a function is changed. Getting this right without inadvertently violating the One Definition Rule is tricky and relies on details of how the objects are linked together. It is again not something that's relevant unless you understand the low-level details.

In the final case, marking a function as `noinline` can make it easier to step through code in the debugger, particularly optimized code, by preventing the compiler from mixing code for multiple functions and by clearly demarking function parameters and return values. It's also useful in cases where you suspect bugs in the compiler itself, since it allows you to localize them to a particular function. This is the most likely reason you'll have for using `noinline`, if you ever do.